# How to setup Google Maps API and Markers correctly

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have recently started working on an android application that includes the GPS tracking of the user's position. 
For that purpose I have gone through Google's guide to setting up the GoogleMaps API for Android and I have (to my knowledge) fully understood the steps it took me to get here including the correct API_KEY and the SHA1 Footprint for the debug version of google maps. 
The included code sends a request for the map information to google's API and upon loading fully sets up the map and places a marker in Sydney.
But it doesn't place the marker. Or move the maps interface to Sydney. It just shows the map and appears to be centering itself around africas west-coast every time for some reason.

Here's how far i've gotten in the Java Activity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pkw__route__content__gps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    try {
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException npe){
        npe.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    current = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


}
```

The fragment looks as follows:

```
    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:layout_width="257dp"
      android:layout_height="224dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

I have added the API key to the Manifest in a  tag called "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY". I will not post it in here for obvious reasons.

As said, the Map initializes correctly but the Markers are not placed and the moveCamera call is also not executed correctly

EDIT:
I think this question needs some more backstory, I am using the Map inside a fragment which is integrated into another activity.
The reason why I think this is important is because I have tried to start the map activity through an intent in which case it will fully load up, place markers and work interactively as it should. Because all of this is in the onCreate() method. How do I do this without having to invoke the Activity and stop the other one?

Answer (score 0):

The map is not loaded when `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` is called. You have to wait for the `OnMapLoadedCallback` Event.

You have set a `OnMapLoadedCallback` to the map in  `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` and set the marker and zoom the map to the location in this callback.